# Eclipse plugin development:How to open a file in external editor programmatically in eclipse plugin development

Tags: excel, eclipse-plugin

I am opening a **.xlsx** file in eclipse .It opens internally in *MS excel* which again contain my *excel plugin*.Which do not work properly when eclipse open excel *internally*.

So how can i set ,eclipse always open *.xlsx* file externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an editor for xlsx in your plugin using the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        extensions="xlsx" 
        id="myeditor.id"
        icon="icon path"
        launcher="myeditor.Launcher"
        name="XLSX editor">
  </editor>
 </extension>
```

This is using the `launcher` attribute to specify that a class to launch an external editor is to be used.

The `Launcher` class would be something like:

```java
public class Launcher implements IEditorLauncher 
{
  public void open(IPath file)
  {
    File file = file.toFile();

    java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where should i write this code ,means when i select a .xlsx file in project explorer and open it ,at that point this code should be called. So either their is some event called when we open a file or i have to override editor or something??

Comment: This code is only of use if it is your plugin that is opening the file. For project explorer I don't think there is a way to force just xlsx to open externally.

Comment: Yes i am creating a plugin .It will contain only .xlsx files,and i just want they should open externally.Am i misunderstanding?

Comment: I have revised the answer to include an editor definition and IEditorLauncher